# Recording Multiple Incoming Video Streams Microsoft Teams (Microsoft Skype Media Bot)

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, skype-bots

I am creating a Microsoft Teams live session recording bot. It is a console application, and I am utilizing Microsoft Graph APIs and Microsoft Skype Media Bot library for handling the call events.

I have successfully configured my bot and able to connect to a 1:1 peer-peer call. Also joining the call. The data I am receiving is from onAudio, OnVideo, OnVbss Media Received events methods of Microsoft Skype Media Bot library.

The problem I want to discuss is that, the recorded video of the session is only supporting single person video feed. For example two person are in the session and both of them keeps their camera open, so, my recorded video will initially, shows the first person video stream and then replace with second person.

My target is to record the video feeds of all of the participants at single time without replacing any or recording the single feed at a time.

Hope I was able to demonstrate my problem. Looking forward for the response.

Comment: Let me check on this Murtaza.

Comment: Ok @Dev waiting for your response.